# Redirect a HTTP page to HTTPS with ProxyPass to Tomcat server

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, redirect, https

So I have a tomcat server running on port 8080, and an apache server running on ports 80 and 443. I can get the whole website to redirect to https by using these virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/crt/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/crt/localhost.key
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPass /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, am trying to get it so that it only redirects to https when the url is `localhost/#/login` or `localhost/catdapp/#/login`

I have tried the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent /#/login https://localhost/#/login
    Redirect permanent /catdapp/#/login https://localhost/#/login
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /#/login !
    ProxyPass /catdapp/#/login !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPass /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which didnt work, the console showed it was retrieving `http://localhost/catdapp/partials/login.html` so I tried changing it to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent /catdapp/partials/login.html https://localhost/catdapp/partials/login.html
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /catdapp/partials/login.html !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPass /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /catdapp http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which then results in the firefox console outputting two errors:

```
GET http://localhost/catdapp/partials/login.html 301 Moved Permanently
GET https://localhost/catdapp/partials/login.html 200 OK
```

The apache access log shows:

```
"GET /catdapp/partials/login.html HTTP/1.1" 301 328 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x84_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
"GET /catdapp/partials/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2054 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x84_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`#` is handled on client side, in the browser - I've not seen it transmitted to the server.

I'd stop worrying about mixed mode operation and just unconditionally redirect everything to https and continue there: With http/https mixed mode you'll just open so many unexpected security holes, session leaks or others that (nowadays) it's just not worth the hassle. Add an [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to the https-virtual-host and you're even safe on the occasions where you've accidentally used the wrong protocol (once the client has seen the HSTS header, which should be the norm)

Will that consume more server-side resources? Probably, a bit. Will it matter? Measure! If you have resources that are worth protecting, it will be worth ruling out a whole class of errors like session information leakage, phishing, MITM attacks etc.